# Python Setting dataframe names from a string stored in a list

Tags: python

I am newer to working in Python and am struggling with creating a for loop that produces several subset data frames based on the values stored in a list.

I have two lists: dataframe_names and ages_list. I need to create individual subset data frames from the data frame "data" that each hold one value from the ages_list. I want to name each of these data frames with the corresponding string held in dataframe_names.

Here is the ages_list :

```
ages_list = ['<30', '30-34', '35-39', '40-44', '45-49', '50-54', '55-59', '60-64', '65-69', '70-74', '75-79', '80-84', '85+']
```

Here is the dataframe names list:

```
dataframe_names = ['age_30', 'age30_34', 'age35_39', 'age40_44', 'age45_49', 'age50_54', 'age55_59', 'age60_64', 'age65_69', 'age70_74', 'age75_79', 'age80_84', 'age85_']
```

This is the code I've tried, which is not working at all

```
for (age,name) in zip(ages_list, dataframe_names):
    name = data[data['AgeGroup']== age]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to include a representation of your dataframe and your expected output. I suspect you don't need a loop at all, but it's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @PaulH, for some reason I am unable to edit and add an example to my original question. The intended output is several data frames with each one holding a separate value of AgeGroup in it from the original data frame "data". AgeGroup holds "<30" , "30-34", etc... I just want to filter so that each dataframe holds one of these unique AgeGroups a piece. These will later be used for plotting, if that makes any difference. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need several dataframes. that's only going to make your life harder. if you're trying to make a plot, ask a question about plotting

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to fix your problem but the data is in a list just change it to the correct dataframe that you use.

This is the code I have wrote:

```
ages_list = ['<30', '30-34', '35-39', '40-44', '45-49', '50-54', '55-59', '60-64', 
'65-69', '70-74', '75-79', '80-84', '85+']

dataframe_names = ['age_30', 'age30_34', 'age35_39', 'age40_44', 'age45_49', 'age50_54', 'age55_59', 'age60_64', 'age65_69', 'age70_74', 'age75_79', 'age80_84', 'age85_']
data = ['<30', '40-44', '85+']
name = []
ind = None
for age in data:
    for agl in data:

        if age == agl:
            ind = ages_list.index(agl)
            name.append(dataframe_names[ind])
            break


print(name)
```

This is what is prints:

```
['age_30', 'age40_44', 'age85_']
```

Comment: The intended output would be to have each item in dataframe_names point to a dataframe. So for instance, age30_34 should be  a dataframe in which data['AgeGroup'] == "30-34". The output after running the code you've provided, just gives a list of names, but they don't point to dataframes.

Comment: You haven't given the dataframe of data so I made it in a list, but from this code, you can change the append of the list to make different dataframes.

Comment: @bziggy you can't assign any type of value to a new variable with strings. if you find yourself wanting to do that you typically need a dictionary. in this case, i strongly encourage you to keep all of your data in a single dataframe